# How to connect to remote weblogic JMS server?

Tags: jms, weblogic, spring-jms, jms-topic

I have a jms server running on weblogic and I need another application running on another server (weblogic as well) to listen to JMS topics sent by the JMS server mentioned before. The fact is that I don't know how to do that. I mean, what do I need on the consumer application side? Thansk in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Foreign JMS provider? What is the typical role of Weblogic in a JMS application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404278/what-is-foreign-jms-provider-what-is-the-typical-role-of-weblogic-in-a-jms-appl)

Comment: Thanks Trent! I'm gonna take a look at the question you've mentioned :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it´s a little old, but could help other people trying to achieve the same.
First you need to enable Cross-Domain Security on both domains envolved on your JMS communication. Please see specific documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/SECMG/domain.htm#SECMG402

For reading a message from a JMS resource, there are a ton of examples you can search online, but basically you should rely on Weblogic´s t3 protocol. Here is a relativelly recent example using Spring Boot: [Connect to remote jms queue with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032248/connect-to-remote-jms-queue-with-spring-boot)